# Как правильно выполнять привязку Entity Framework WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

У меня в проекте есть partial-классы сгенерированных EF poco-классов. В них имеются публичные свойства, которые считают на основании данных некоторые значения : сумму товара в заказе и итог заказа.

На данный момент мои классы выглядят так:

**POCO-класс заказа:**

```
    public partial class ORDERS
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ORDERS()
        {
            this.ORDERS_COMPOSE = new HashSet<ORDERS_COMPOSE>();
            this.SALES = new HashSet<SALES>();
        }
    
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int USER_ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DATE { get; set; }
        public int CLIENT { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DELIVERY_DATE { get; set; }
    
        public virtual CLIENTS CLIENTS { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ORDERS_COMPOSE> ORDERS_COMPOSE { get; set; }
        public virtual USERS USERS { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SALES> SALES { get; set; }
    }
```

**POCO-класс состава заказа (свойство QUANTITY мне пришлось перенести в partial):**

```
public partial class ORDERS_COMPOSE
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
    public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ORDERS ORDERS { get; set; }
    public virtual PRODUCT PRODUCT { get; set; }
}
```

**PARTIAL-класс состава заказа (здесь происходит наследование Notify):**

```
public partial class ORDERS_COMPOSE : Notify
{
    public decimal Sum => QUANTITY * PRODUCT.PRICE;
    private int _quantity;
    public int QUANTITY {
        get => _quantity;
        set { _quantity = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Sum)); ORDERS?.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ORDERS.Total)); } }
}
```

**PARTIAL-класс заказа (здесь происходит наследование Notify):**

```
public partial class ORDERS : Notify
{
    public decimal Total => ORDERS_COMPOSE.Select(x => x.Sum).Sum();
}
```

**VIEW-model:**

```
   public class VM_Order : Notify
    {
        private KASSAEntities db;
        public VM_Order(ORDERS order = null)
        {
            db = new KASSAEntities();

            if (order != null)
            {
                Order = db.ORDERS.Include(x => x.ORDERS_COMPOSE)
                    .First(x => x.ID == order.ID);

            }
            else
            {
                Order = db.ORDERS.Add(new ORDERS());
            }
            Products = db.ORDERS_COMPOSE.Local.ToBindingList();
        }

        private ORDERS _orders;
        public ORDERS Order { get => _orders; set { _orders = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public BindingList<ORDERS_COMPOSE> Products { get; set; }

    }
```

Проблема состоит в том, что по информации в интернете, в POCO-классы лучше никаким образом не лезть и ничего не изменять, а все изменения необходимо обновлять через ViewModel, которая  наследует Notify(INotifyPropertyChanged).

С этим кодом всё работает замечательно. Если эта архитектура неправильна, то как правильно оповещать об обновлении свойства?

Я предполагаю, что POCO-классы нельзя редактировать, т.к. они могут поставляться в приложение через dll-библиотеку. Тогда изменение структуры (в моём случае удаление поля quantity и перемещение в partial-класса ORDER_COMPOSE) будет невозможно.
Плюc, скорее всего, сейчас архитектуры приложений предрасположены на использование WEB-API, но в моём приложении это пока не нужно.

Может нужно делать класс-обёртку, в котором уже реализуются расчётные свойства, который наследуется или содержит ссылку на объект?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Если вы работаете с WPF, то вам надо UI / VM / Models. Ваши POCO - могут играть роль моделей, но не вьюмоделей. Если надо биндить UI на что то - делайте вьюмодель и биндите. Архитектура вашего приложения должна быть одинаковой, не зависимо от того, грузите вы данные их БД или откуда ещё.

Comment: @tym32167B, добавила код VM. Приложение построено на MVVM.

Comment: либо я не понял вопроса, либо вы сами на него ответили. `как правильно оповещать об обновлении свойства?` => `set { _orders = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }`

Comment: @tym32167, дело в том, что мне при изменении свойства количества товара нужно обновлять сумму и итог. Оповещение сейчас реализовано с помощью изменений в poco-классах. И я где-то читала, что это не правильно, и Notify тоже нельзя наследовать. Что нужно как-то оповещать через ViewModel (т.е. Notify должен реализовываться только во VM). Но как отследить изменение свойства QUANTITY, если оно находится очень "глубоко" в иерархии, да и сам класс не наследует Notify?

Comment: кто что у вас меняет? Как выглядит сценарий? Если юзер тыкат в интерфейс и что то меняет, интерфейс привязками обновляет VM, которая наследуется от INPC и тем самым любой может подписаться на обновление любого поля.

Comment: что такое "оповещение через изменение poco классов" - я набор слов вижу, но смысла фразы не понимаю

Comment: @tym32167, это значит, что poco-классы у меня наследуют Notify и используют в некоторых свойствах OnPropertyChanged, что по мнению из интернета не должно происходить - я вообще не должна никак изменять их, если я правильно поняла.

Comment: Как я поняла, предполагается, что OnPropertyChanged должен вызываться при каких-либо событиях на View (т.е. на каждую функцию нужно прописывать во ViewModel, в этих функциях вызывать необходимые OnPropertyChanged и вызывать эти функции на событиях форм.

Comment: poco классы служат чисто для передачи информации. Например, записи в БД или отправке по сети. Если вы на низ какие то другие обязанности вешаете - то по сути да, вы неверно их используете.